# Increasing performance when searching for customers in Oracle DB with 3 products with temp tables or function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

in an Oracle DB I tried to get a list of customers who have a combination of up to 3 different products (entered from the user). In order to get this list my first Idea was to use temp-tables.
Select a list of customers who have the first product, save it in a temp-table. Selecting customers out of that temp-table who have the second product, save it in another temp-table. Then selecting customers out of this new temp-table who have the third product. After printing the result on screen, the temp-tables are dropped.

This works more ore less well, but with every user who starts this query 3 temp-tables will be produced on the database. Another problem comes along with the mass of data. The product table stores 1 entry for every product sold to a customer, so it has up to 26 million entries.

A second approach, in my opinion, could be to use a function to make these checks. But I don't know if that would increase the performance. Because the variables/arrays would be very big.

I don't see another way to increase performance at the moment, so I would appreciate any help.

P.S.: I only have the permission to create temp-tables or a procedure/function on that database. I cannot set views or indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use temp tables for this.  There is no need at all and you lose the power of using SQL. You can do the same thing in one query, using `intersect`:

```
select t.customer
from table t
where t.product = v_product1
intersect
select t.customer
from table t
where t.product = v_product2
intersect
select t.customer
from table t
where t.product = v_product3;
```

There are definitely alternative approaches.  I would typically write this as something like this:

```
select customer
from table t
where product in (v_product1, v_product2, v_product3)
group by customer
having count(distinct product) = 3;
```

Although the `intersect` query might have better performance.

Comment: +1 for the GROUP/HAVING combination. I've done actually used that pattern.

Comment: @Thilo . . . You are so right.  That should have been `t.customer` not `t.*`.

Comment: Great, intersect is the solution! Thank you, I completely forgot that in oracle intersect works. (cause in mysql it didn't)